# Exponential Families and Riemannian Symmetric Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, manifolds

Suppose the $f_{X}(x|\theta)$ is a probability density function from an exponential family. Is it true that the Riemannian manifold which has the Fisher information as it's Riemannian metric is a homogeneous space? Better yet is it a Riemannian symmetric space?